# CSS-Logo in header disappears when adding paading-left

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink, header

I have the logo image as a link to homepage in the header on the left, along with other nav links on the right. However, the logo disappears when I add the "padding-left" property to the inline CSS of the  attribute. enter code here

Strangely enough, the same code (with the padding-left attribute) works fine for the headers of other pages of the same website.

So, here;s the snapshot from when the left-padding is 1%:
[left-padding is 1%](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rugmf2vxl26uxpb/demo1.PNG?dl=0)

the snapshot from when the left-padding is 3%:
[left-padding is 3%](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ee8q296mz9qqmu0/demo2.PNG?dl=0)

If you look closely, the right boundary of the image is fixed at a certain point horizontally. So when I increase the left-padding, the image is being compressed from the left and is becoming smaller.

What I'm expecting is the image to be moved to the left, altogether, without being compressed.

Here's the code :

```css
#header {
        width: 100%;
        height: 10%;
        color: white;
        background-color: #0066CC;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
```

```html
<div id="header">

    <a href="homepage.html"><img id="logo" src="logo.png" alt="HZ Innovations" style = "float: left; width: 5%; height: 100%; padding-left: 10%;"/></a>
    <div id = "headLinks" style="float: right; position: absolute; bottom: 10%; right: 25%; ">
        <a href="about.html" >About Hz</a>&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;
        <a href="technology.html">The Technology</a>&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;
        <a href="contactUs.html" >Contact Us</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does that snippet look like what you're trying to show? is it relevant to your question?

Comment: Yes, that snippet is the code that's not working. I'm talking about logo.png inside <a> not being displayed. @Amit

Comment: We'll need a demo with an actual image. Also it makes no sense to both float and position absolute the `headlinks` div...use one or the ther...not both.

Comment: Well, currently snippets aren't working (Bug? Maintenance?), so it's impossible to answer. But the question is about `padding-left`, and that's not in the snippet at all

Comment: wer is paddding left?

Comment: Wasn't working with left-padding so when I pasted the code it wasn't included. My bad. The code is updated now.

Comment: Which browser are you seeing the problem in? I'm having trouble reproducing the problem in Chrome, Firefox, Opera, or even IE11.

Comment: I'm using Chrome.... I've attached the dropbox link to the problem's snapchat in the post now..@Jwashton

Answer (score 0):

Answer here, I don't know why it's not working before, but you always should write your HTML correctly!

```css
#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    color: white;
    background-color: #0066CC;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#logo {
    width: 5%;
    height: 100%;f
    float: left;
    padding-left: 100px;
}

#headLinks {
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10%;
    right: 25%;
}

#headLinks > a {
    display: block;
    margin-right: 10px;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
    <a href="homepage.html">
        <img id="logo" src="logo.png" alt="Logo"/>
    </a>
    <div id = "headLinks">
        <a href="about.html">About </a>
        <a href="technology.html">The Technology</a>
        <a href="contactUs.html">Contact Us</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sure, I know it wans't the most readable of the codes you'll see. I'll definitely keep this in mind. Thanks a lot @AleshaOleg